# Do you need protection against CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors

I have a `domain/logout.php`-file to log the user out. As I've understood it, a hacker could on his website let the victims send a CORS-request to my server with the `credentials` on. This will send the request to my server, it will log out the user, but since my server doesn't send the correct headers back, the victims browser will not display the output of `domain/logout.php`.

So, hackers can use CORS to send requests that does more evil things than just logging out the user, but it will not get response of the server as long as the server doesn't include the right CORS-headers.

Why did W3C really implement this when it has this security hole?

Comment: Question first: Are you vulnerable to that? Because if not, you don't need the protection. So test first if you are vulnerable, then you know if you need protection or not.

Comment: @hakre Well, I am. I have a file that is called domain/logout.php that logs the user out. So if someone does this, the victim would be logged out. Am I right?

Comment: Seeing you asking me *"Am I right?"* tells me that you have not tested if you are vulnerable or not yet. You have identified a potential part of your application that *might* be vulnerable, but you have not tested it yet. Test it now. If you have a problem how to do a test-setup you should probably ask about it in your question.

Comment: @hakre Why did they implement this when it poses a security hole?

Comment: This is a question about CSRF rather than CORS.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts: Human sense dictates that W3C does security reviews, so it's more likely this is something you don't understand in the first place *before* you should conclude that W3C did suggested something with a not yet so far noticed security implication. Most W3C documents should have at least a chapter about  the security implications of a standard. Locate that one and read if your case is in there. Also read what that is you ask about in the first place, it looks like you are totally fishing blindly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused about CORS. CORS headers are sent by servers and are not part of a request by any client. Clients just interpret them if they support them.

Secondly this becomes important if you are dealing with client side scripting, specially jquery and javascript ajax in general. for Server to server communication CORS is not needed for anyone to log your customer out like that.

For any outside request to your logout form the client first has to be logged in before being "logged out", otherwise there is no one to be logged out.

For PHP - PHP communications you do not need CORS. You would need protection against unauthorized access, Specially for areas where database operations take place

Comment: Hmm, how can one protect against CORS then? Do I need to implement a CSRF in the URL?